# MVC3 JSON call issue with IIS

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I'm working on MVC3 UserManagement and on local (VS2010) all seems to be working fine but on IIS(7.5) it just won't show any response to JSON post.

Table for users generator:

```
this.init = function (tableSelector) {

// get user table
userTable = $(tableSelector);

// fill the user table with all 
$.post('/{controllerName}/GetAllUsers', {}, function (users) {

  // add users to table
  for (var i in users) {
    appendUser(users[i]);
  }

  //initialize table sorter and pager
  userTable.tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'] }).tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false, removeRows: false });

  // bind user action link event handlers for all rows
  userTable.on('click', '.delete-user', deleteUser);
  userTable.on("click", ".unlock-user", unlockUser);
  userTable.on("click", ".manage-roles", manageRoles);
});
```

}

Routes register method:

```
public static void RegisterMe()
{

  var routes = RouteTable.Routes;

  using (routes.GetWriteLock())
  {
    routes.MapRoute("SimpleUserManagementRoute",
      "SimpleUserManagement/{action}",
      new { controller = "UserManagement", action = "GetAllUsers" },
      new string[] { "SimpleMvcUserManagement" });
  }

}
```

Controller part:

```
public IUserAccountService _accountService { get; set; }

public JsonResult GetAllUsers()
{
  var users = _accountService.GetAllUsers();
  var result = from MembershipUser user in users
               select CreateJsonUserObject(user);

  return Json(result);
}
```

Now  by looking around StackOverflow, I've found that issue lies with strong-coded URL.
Reference: [MVC 3 JSON call not working in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044059/mvc-3-json-call-not-working-in-iis)

And i've tried replacing my URLs with those mentioned in the reference, but of course it didn't work since I don't know where/how to `stringify` my url :( , also not sure if that solution would even work with this.

Please help. TY!

Comment: what's the error? not found 400? internal error 500?

Comment: Usually you just post directly to the route, you don't need to include the controller.

Comment: You can stringify using Douglas Crockfords JSON.js available here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has your IIS been configured with a virtual directory? What happens if you put /{controllerName}/GetAllUsers into your browser? Do you get a response or a 404?

Comment: I get 404. But when I use `/{controllerName}/GetAllUsers` it does indeed show it like `/UserManagement/GetAllUsers` just it's not showing any return data... Only 404 on response

Comment: If you can hit the breakpoint you can step through and see var users is empty?

Comment: I don't have dev environment on server, just in local, and on local everything works... Meaning, nothing to debug with on server.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are passing to the `$.post` is wrong.

It should be either,

`$.post("/Register/GetAllUsers", ...)` // assuming the controller is RegisterController

or

```
$.post('@Url.Action("GetAllUsers", "Register")',..
```

Comment: My Urls are fine since they work on local, I've tried with Url Helpers , but same thing happens, on server error 404.